# How is $C_0^nC_n^{n+1}+ C_1^nC_{n-1}^{n}+C_2^nC_{n-2}^{n-1}+\dots+C_n^n C_0^{1} =2^{n-1}(n+2) ?$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

How is $$C_0^nC_n^{n+1}+ C_1^nC_{n-1}^{n}+C_2^nC_{n-2}^{n-1}+\dots+C_n^n C_0^{1} =2^n(n+2) ?$$ 
I have no idea how to approach this problem. There is no solution given in my book. There doesn't seem to be any pattern here. Would someone please help?

Comment: $C_k^{n}C_{n-k}^{n+1-k}=\cfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\cfrac{(n+1-k)!}{1!(n-k!)}=\cfrac{(n+1)!-kn!}{k!(n-k)!}=\cfrac{(n+1)!}{k!(n-k)!}-\cfrac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}$, which looks like it should telescope somehow

Comment: @Hema The right-hand side is not correct. For $n=1$:
$$C_0^1 C_1^{2}+ C_1^1C_{0}^{1}=2+1=3\not=4=2(1+1).$$ 
Please check your statement.

Comment: @RobertZ I had made a typo actually, I've rectified it now.

Comment: @Hema Now it is correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Note  that
$$C^{n+1-k}_{n-k}=\frac{(n+1-k)!}{(n-k)!1!}=(n+1-k).$$
Hence
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^nC_k^{n}C_{n-k}^{n+1-k}&=(n+1)\sum_{k=0}^nC_k^{n}-\sum_{k=0}^nkC_k^{n}\\
&=(n+1)\sum_{k=0}^nC_k^{n}-n\sum_{k=1}^nC_{k-1}^{n-1}.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the series and sum, like nine-year-old Gauss did.